# Number() fails to convert the string to number in map()

Tags: javascript

The following comes the code snippet in which there is a two dimensional array from which I want to alter the string value nested at the second level at index 0.

```
const dataset = [
  ["1947-01-01", 243.1],
  ["1947-04-01", 246.3],
  ["1947-07-01", 250.1],
];
const datasetXY = dataset.map((first) =>
  first.map((second) => {
    if (typeof second == "string") {
      const returnedValue =
        Number(second.substring(0, 4)) +
        (Number(second.substring(5, 7)) / 12).toFixed(2);
      return returnedValue;
    } else {
      return second;
    }
  })
);
```

The returned array should be like the following:(whether it's rounded to the second decimal place doesn't matter that much). However, the returned values at the second level at index 0 are still "**string**" rather than **number**. Is there anything I mess up above?

```
  [
    [
      1947.01,
      243.1
    ],
    [
      1947.34,
      246.3
    ],
    [
      1947.58,
      250.1
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a string. If you use the + operator on a number and a string, you will get a string. If you're going to take this approach, you need to convert the result to a number yet again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, `.toFixed()` returns a string! This converts your whole number back to a string.

the fix is easy : just `return +returnedValue` (quick conversion, similar to `Number(returnedValue)`)

```js
const dataset = [
  [
    "1947-01-01",
    243.1
  ],
  [
    "1947-04-01",
    246.3
  ],
  [
    "1947-07-01",
    250.1
  ]
]
const datasetXY = dataset.map(first => first.map(second => {
  if (typeof second == "string") {
    const returnedValue =
      Number(second.substring(0, 4)) +
      (Number(second.substring(5, 7)) / 12).toFixed(2)
    return +returnedValue
  } else {
    return second
  }
}))

console.log(datasetXY)
```

This is the kind of bug that Typescript easily prevents. By typing your function (`first.map( (second:string|number):number => {...`), Typescript would tell you "Your function is expected to return a number, but it's returning a string".

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed()` returns a string. You can explicitly convert the value returned by `toFixed()` to type number.

```
const dataset = [
  ["1947-01-01", 243.1],
  ["1947-04-01", 246.3],
  ["1947-07-01", 250.1],
];
const datasetXY = dataset.map((first) =>
  first.map((second) => {
    if (typeof second == "string") {
      const returnedValue =
        Number(second.substring(0, 4)) +
        Number((Number(second.substring(5, 7)) / 12).toFixed(2)); // explicitly convert value returned by .toFixed() to number
      return returnedValue;
    } else {
      return second;
    }
  })
);
```